# If $f(x)=g(x) \ \forall x\in (-1,1)$, is it true $f(iy)=g(iy) \ \forall y\in (-1,1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> If $f$ and $g$ admit power series in the ball $B(0,1)$ and $f(x)=g(x) \ \forall x\in (-1,1)$, does it follow that $f(iy)=g(iy) \ \forall y\in (-1,1)$?

My answer is true. As $f$ and $g$ both admit power series in the ball $B(0,1)$, then $f\in H(B(0,1))$ and $g\in H(B(0,1))$.

Now if  $f(x)=g(x) \ \forall x\in (-1,1)$, then  $f(z)=g(z) \ \forall z\in B(0,1)$. So it follows that $ f(iy)=g(iy) \ \forall y\in (-1,1)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is 100% correct!

Comment: Does it matter that $\pm i\notin B(0,1)$? As $B(0,1)$ is an open set.

Comment: You are not bothered about $\pm i$. The question is about $\pm iy$ with $|y|<1$.

Comment: Oh of course, thank you!! But if the boundary was included, then my reasoning would be false and hence the question untrue?